# How implement ManyToOne delete on cascade?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is my code

```
@Entity
    public class School{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
    }

    @Entity
    public class Student{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;

        @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
        @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID")
        private School school;  
    }
```

Im using JPA delete (Impl code)

```
@Autowired
    SchoolRepository sr;
    @Override
    void delete(Integer id) throws Exception {
        sr.deleteById(id);}
```

In another answer it says to set all his child to null , how i make this? Is there any way to make it easier? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add one List of Student on Entity School annotated by @OneToMany with cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, to remove all students of school.

```
@Entity
public class School{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy = "school")
    private List<Student> students;

}

@Entity
public class Student{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID")
    private School school;  
}
```